# Best and Economic Domain Purchase and hosting for asp.net app

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Hi Guys I have created an asp.net application and now i want to publish it on the internet and want to place different ads like Google Adsense etc on it. I don't have a Domain name. So please suggest me a hosting service which is technically better (Providees easy to manage control panel for your site etc) and cheap.

Comment: I am using [eWebGuru](http://www.ewebguru.com/) and i am satisfied with their services

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with discountasp.net